# while passing parameter in retrun view from controller to blade getting error in foreach

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Getting Error In Laravel foreach loop.

Controller is

```
$userprojectObjs = works::getProjects();

return view('admin.users.self_assign',['userprojectObjs'=>json_encode($userprojectObjs)]);
```

Blade is

```
@foreach ($userprojectObjs  as $key=>  $userprojectObjs )
                               <tr>
                                    <td>{{$userprojectObjs->Number}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$userprojectObjs->Name}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$userprojectObjs->Type}}</td>
                               <tr>
@endforeach
```

It showing Invalid argument supplied for foreach() ;

Comment: Why `json_encode()` it?

Comment: there is no need to use `json_encode`

Comment: post your getProjects function code

Answer (score 2):

Remove `json_encode`.It's already a collection.No need to use `json_encode`.

```
@forelse ($userprojectObjs  as $key=>  $userprojectObjs )
    <tr>
    <td>{{$userprojectObjs->Number}}</td>
    <td>{{$userprojectObjs->Name}}</td>
    <td>{{$userprojectObjs->Type}}</td>
    <tr>
@empty
    <p>No user projects</p>
@endforelse
```

Answer (score 0):

Need not to use json_encode in the controller.

Or you can loop like this

```
@foreach (json_decode($userprojectObjs)  as $key=>  $userprojectObjs )
     <tr>
       <td>{{$userprojectObjs->Number}}</td>
       <td>{{$userprojectObjs->Name}}</td>
       <td>{{$userprojectObjs->Type}}</td>
     <tr>
@endforeach
```